# Criar Blocos HTML no Wordpress e chamá-los na Post ou Page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Temos um site de imóveis onde utilizamos ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) para melhor gerenciar as páginas de imóveis.

Um dos campos é a Tabela de Preços.

Uma tabela de preços de um condomínio serve para várias páginas de imóveis do mesmo condomínio, consequentemente, quando há uma mudança em valor ou disponibilidade, devemos mudar a tabela em todos os imóveis deste condomínio.

Estava pensando em criar BLOCOS HTML (no caso seriam as tabelas) e depois chamá-los nas páginas.

Por exemplo: nas 10 páginas do empreendimento TESTE eu quero chamar a "TABELA DE PREÇOS DO EMPREENDIMENTOT TESTE".

Essa tabela seria um bloco criado (mesma ideia de um widget text/html).

Alguém conhece algo já pronto, ou tem ideia de como fazer?

Valeuuu!

Answer (score 1):

Boa Tarde Tiago,

Você pode usar um plugin chamado TablePress, disponivel nessa URL (https://wordpress.org/plugins/tablepress/)

Esse plugin você vai criar as tabelas e depois com um shortcode, vai inserir a tabela nos posts que desejar. Quando você atualizar uma tabela, automaticamente, todos os posts que contem essa tabela serão atualizados.

Acho que é isso.

Sucesso ae.

Answer (score 0):

Se você está usando o ACF, pode usar o método `get_field()` dele mesmo, onde quer que você deseje fazer o display do valor.

Leia mais sobre ele na [documentação](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).